# How to achieve asyncronous testing using SOAPUI

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, soapui, routes, asynchronous-postback

(sorry about the length of my request)

Current technology that I use to achieve asynchronous testing :
1. ssh into our server ex) svr.server.com (located elsewhere in a datacentre)
2. create a v.host myname.server.com
3. use some script to make curl request (xml as post) to svr.server.com (from the same svr.server.com)
note: the request xml will have a callback url (which is nothing but my v.host address) that the server will use to callback with a response xml

what I have:
I have my.testbox.com in my company that can make request to svr.server.com (located elsewhere in a datacentre)
But the server doesn't know how to get back to my box. (that's why I use the above mentioned "current technology", because there's no route)
(I know I need to add a route, but not sure where and how - that can be a different topic)

Now, I want to be:
Able to fire all my requests [xml as POST](from my office) to the server without waiting for a response (asynchronously) to svr.server.com (located elsewhere in a datacentre)and the server should be able to respond back with the xml.

And I will be performing various assertions on the response xml.

Can someone please let me know if this is possible using SOAPUI or SOAPUI pro ?
If 'yes', how ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, soapUI can launch multiple requests simultaneously and wait for the response for a custom amount of time and then assert different things about the response. What you are trying to achieve is actually called load testing.
See url for further info: http://www.soapui.org/Load-Testing/simulating-different-types-of-load.html

P.S.: I don't know about your network related issue though (reverse DNS?). That doesn't seem something you could fix with soapUI.